# Trying to include a header file into main.cpp, but VS2010 gives me errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header-files

I am trying to use a simple header file in my main cpp, but my compiler keeps generating errors. It generates errors if the code I want to be in the header file is in the header file; if there is no code in the header file, and the code I want to be in the header file is in the main cpp, the compiler will generate no errors. I have checked to make sure the header file is in the same location as my main, and yes, since I am using Allegro for making a game, I have made sure to link the debug lib; all of that stuff is taken care of.

Here is my code:

main.cpp (without code I want to be in the header file):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <allegro5\allegro5.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "Globals.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = NULL;

    if(!al_init())  
    {
        if(errorFile.is_open())
            errorFile << "Allegro failed to initialize.";
        return -1;
    }

    display = al_create_display(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);           

    if(!display)    
    {
        if(errorFile.is_open())
            errorFile << "ALLEGRO_DISPLAY failed to initialize.";
        return -1;
    }

    if(errorFile.bad())
    {
        cout << "errorFile is bad";
    }

    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_install_keyboard();

    event_queue = al_create_event_queue();
    timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / 60);

    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));

    al_start_timer(timer);

    while(!done)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
        al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);
        if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
        {
            if(ev.timer.source == timer)
            {

            }
        }
        if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
        {
            done = true;
        }
        if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            switch(ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                    done = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP)
        {
            switch(ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                    done = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(redraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(event_queue))
        {
            al_flip_display();
            al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
        }
    }
    al_destroy_display(display);
    al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    errorFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the header file, "Globals.h", with the desired code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 600;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
bool done = true;
bool redraw = true;

enum KEYS {UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT};
bool keys[4] = {false,false,false,false};

ofstream errorFile ("errorFile.txt", ios::trunc);
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I heard about a compiler error, but I don't see any actual error in your post. I'm not a compiler.

Comment: You should use a namespace. You're missing `std::ofstream` on `ofstream` too.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick, thanks so much for the quick reply!

Comment: When posting questions involving compiler errors, please always post the error message. It makes things a lot easier for people to answer.

Comment: Apologies, will remember to do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting " "  around the #include allegro headers, this tells the compiler to look in the project directory first. Although you could put the error log in your post.